# Transform a model-space vector into clip-space

Tags: 3d, stage3d

I am implementing a simple vertex shader to billboard a bitmap. 4 vertices are defined and for each the vertex shader uses the respective UV, in conjunction with the bitmaps width/height divided by the viewport width/height, to modify clip-space position. Pretty typical stuff, here's some stub code for that:

```
    // Project positions to clip space.
    float4 clipPosition = vertexPosition * objectToClipSpaceTransform;

    // Get constants.
    float2 viewPort = float2(props[0], props[1]);
    float2 spriteSize = float2(props[2], props[3]);

    // Calculate window offset.
    float2 windowOffset;
    windowOffset.x = (vertexUV.x - 0.5) * spriteSize.x;
    //neg because V increases down, but Y in clip-space increases up
    windowOffset.y = -(vertexUV.y - 0.5) * spriteSize.y;  
    windowOffset /= viewPort;

    clipPosition.xy += windowOffset * clipPosition.w * 2.0;

    // Output shifted vertex.
    vertexClipPosition = clipPosition;
```

What I want to do, is offset the bitmap in the direction of a vector defined in world-space whose magnitude is a fixed number of pixels. The tricky part here is how to convert a world-space vector into clip-space. I have tried using the objectToClipSpaceTransform without the translation component, but the result is not correct. So, how do I do this?

Comment: Are you asking about OpenGL, or Direct3D? Because they use two different clip-spaces. So which is it?

Comment: I was intentionally vague to try to reach the greatest audience of expertise. My exact 3D environment is actually Flash's stage3D API, with a x(-1, 1) y(-1, 1) z(-1, 1) clip-space. However, the particulars of the clip-space I am using don't really apply to my question as I believe it is pretty general.

Answer (score 1):

To transform a world space vector into clip space, multiply by the worldViewProjection transform, and divide the final vector by its w component.

It is important to make sure that the fourth component of the original vector is 0, since 0 is used for direction vectors, and 1 is used for location vectors.

So if your vector is v = (x,y,z,0)

Then (assuming row major matrices) the resulting vector is

```
vclip = v * worldViewProjection.
```

The last step is called the homogeneous divide, which is important if the projection is perspective.  You need to divide the new vector by its 4th component
ie:

```
vclip = vclip / vclip.w;
```